# Make Launcher2 standalone

Tags: android, android-launcher

I would like to make Launcher2 (AOSP Launcher) a standalone data app (not system) for my Android 4.1.1 device (Branch jb-release; API Level 16).

I cannot find any resources on what to modify to make it standalone, so I tried it myself.
Hope someone can help me doing that (for error list see lists below).

Source code can be found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/jb-release/src/com/android/launcher2

**AppsCustomizedPagedView.java:**

```
The import android.graphics.Insets cannot be resolved
The import android.graphics.TableMaskFilter cannot be resolved
```

I guess both are due to `@Hide`. Any workaround or good solution here?

**Cling.java:**

```
The method findViewToTakeAccessibilityFocusFromHover(View, View) of type Cling must override or implement a supertype method (Class Cling extends android.widget.FrameLayout)
The method includeForAccessibility() is undefined for the type View
```

**HolographicOutlineHelper.java:**

```
The import android.graphics.TableMaskFilter cannot be resolved
```

Same as in AppsCustomizedPagedView.java (`@Hide`)

**Launcher.java:**

```
The import android.os.SystemProperties cannot be resolved
The import com.android.common cannot be resolved
The method clearAllAnimations() is undefined for the type ValueAnimator
The method startSearch(String, boolean, ComponentName, Bundle, boolean) in the type SearchManager is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean, ComponentName, Bundle, boolean, Rect)
SystemProperties cannot be resolved
The method requestAccessibilityFocus() is undefined for the type Cling
```

**PagedViewWidgetImageView.java:**

```
The import android.graphics.Insets cannot be resolved
The method getLayoutInsets() is undefined for the type Drawable
```

**RocketLauncher.java:**

```
The import android.support cannot be resolved
The constructor RocketLauncher.Board(RocketLauncher, null) is undefined
```

**SearchDropTargetBar.java:**

```
The method getCompatibilityInfo() is undefined for the type Resources
```

**Utilities.java:**

```
The import android.graphics.TableMaskFilter cannot be resolved
```

**Workspace.java:**

```
The method getRealMetrics(DisplayMetrics) is undefined for the type Display
The method setChildrenLayersEnabled(boolean) is undefined for the type ViewGroup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something a lot of people seem to want to do, and something I did a while back.

I got Launcher2 to compile and run as an independent app, and then open sourced my efforts [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/CompilingLauncher2).

This is the Launcher2 from ICS, not JB, but they are very similar. Note that it is not completely bug free, and adding widgets will crash the app (as it uses a system level permission. Maybe if you installed via root it'll work).

Here's a list of what all I had to do, that I can recall doing:

There are lots of methods like `setFastXXX` (for example, `setFastAlpha()`) that aren't available to us. Changing these to `setXXX` (for example, 'setAlpha()`) worked for me.

Some thing which are available to us via `getSystemService()` are initialized directly in the code, like the usage of the Vibrator class. These need to be changed to use `getSystemService()`

I ended up copying a lot of methods out of the Android source code directly into my classes.

You can checkout a fresh version of the ICS launcher2, and run a diff against the one I opensourced to see the full change list.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really nice base to start working from! That's what I will do. Which released version did you started from? mr0 or mr1?

Comment: @dtrunk You're welcome! I'll edit my post with a small list of changes I made to get it to compile.

Comment: @dtrunk I don't remember which version I used. I did the coding almost a year ago (sometime in June I think), but only open sourced it recently after seeing a lot of people trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @AlexFlint Import and compile as a normal Eclipse Android Project

Comment: @RaghavSood: This is nice, but I'm confused by the "fill_screens.py" at the top level. This is likely because I'm using Android Studio instead of Eclipse, but maybe you can help me understand what that's supposed to do

Comment: @CubsFanRon I haven't the slightest idea. I literally took the code out of AOSP, and modified it to compile on its own. I didn't delete or change anything I don't understand, and that file is one of the things I have no clue about.

Comment: @RaghavSood: Thanks for the follow-up. Neither yours nor the LauncherJellyBean version want to work correctly in "user space" after the initial launch and I was hopeful someone could point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 2):

There is a standalone Android JellyBean Launcher hosted on GitHub by chrislacy, and you can add AppWidgets to the home screen:) https://github.com/chrislacy/LauncherJellyBean

Comment: I can't seem to get that to run as a standalone app - it starts, but it doesn't respond to touches in the bottom bar area (you know, where the phone, contacts, all apps, messaging, and browser icons are).